# chai-redux-mock-store - ReferenceError: createMockStore is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, chai

I'm following the example on https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-redux-mock-store and don't understand why createMockStore is undefined.

***package.json***

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js 'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)'",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
```

***test/test_helper.js***

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiReduxMockStore from 'chai-redux-mock-store';

chai.use(chaiReduxMockStore);
```

***test/components/Login/Login_spec.jsx***

```
const store = createMockStore();
```

***npm run test***

```
ReferenceError: createMockStore is not defined
```

***Fix***

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

const createMockStore = (getState) => {
    const middlewares = [];
    return configureStore(middlewares)(getState);
};

const store = createMockStore();

const component = renderIntoDocument(
   <Provider store={store}>
      <LoginContainer />
   </Provider>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createMockStore` isn't something that the library itself exposes, it's something that you need to write yourself.
It stems from the `redux-mock-store` library.

You can have a look at the [tests](https://github.com/themouette/chai-redux-mock-store/blob/3fda837f25c7b36121ac1379e20c55472042aa42/index-test.js#L11) in `chai-redux-mock-store` to figure out how it's supposed to be done.

```
const configureStore = require('redux-mock-store').default;
const createMockStore = (getState) => {
    const middlewares = [];
    return configureStore(middlewares)(getState);
};
```